# Pass @protocol type in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift-protocols, swift3

I have an Objective-C method which takes Protocol* type as parameter.

How can I invoke this method in Swift.

Example:

```
// In Objective-C

@protocol AProtocol <NSObject>
@end

@interface MyClass : NSObject
+ (id)proxyWithProtocol:(Protocol*)protocol;
@end

// I can call this method with a protocol as parameter
[MyClass proxyWithProtocol:@protocol(AProtocol)];
```

If I want to use MyClass in Swift by bridging. How can I pass a protocol defined in Objective-C to proxyWithProtocol method. Can I even pass a protocol defined in Swift to this method?

Comment: Look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) (Using Swift from Objective-C)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would pass the Objective-C protocol in like so:

```
MyClass.proxyWithProtocol(AProtocol)
```

If you wanted to pass in a Swift protocol, you would have to expose that protocol to Objective-C:

```
@objc protocol MyProtocol {
    func someGreatFunc()
}

// ...

MyClass.proxyWithProtocol(MyProtocol)
```

In Swift 3, depending on the way the class is bridged to Swift, your function might look like this:

```
MyClass.proxy(with: AProtocol)
MyClass.proxy(with: MyProtocol)
```

Although the compiler isn't happy with the location of "with" and may complain.

Comment: In Swift 3.0, I cannot pass AProtocol directly. I must use Protocol!(AProtocol)

Comment: @wqyfavor you did not specify you were using Swift 3 in your question.

Comment: "AProtocol.self" and "MyProtocol.self" is also OK

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that.